Why is it not generally possible to extend the measure associated with a locally bounded variation function to all of $\mathbb R_+$?
Let $g: [0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a right-continuous function of locally bounded variation. It is well-known that on every compact interval $[0,T]$, we can define a unique Radon (signed) measure $\mu_T$ such that
$$ \forall 0 \leq a <b \leq T, \quad \mu_T(a,b] = g(b) -g(a). $$
and that the definition is consistent for any $T>0$, in the sense that, if $0<S<T$ and $A$ is a Borel subset of $[0,S]$ then
$$ \mu_S(A) = \mu_T(A). $$
However, in his book "Introduction to Stochastic Integration, Chung said that it is generally not true that we can extend this measure to all of $\mathbb R_+ = [0,+\infty)$. I wonder why?
Can we find a counter-example in which there is no Radon (signed) measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R_+$ that is consistent with $(\mu_T)_{T>0}$ above, in the sense that if $A$ is a bounded Borel set of $\mathbb R_+$, then $\mu(A) = \mu_T(A)$ whenever $T$ satisfies $A \subset [0,T]$?
A side question: If $g$ is increasing, can we extend $(\mu_T)_{T>0}$ to a Radon $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on all of $\mathbb R_+$? (sorry if this is too trivial, but I need to confirm this...)

Here is a simple counter-example.
Let $g: [0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined as $g(x) = \sin (x)$. Then $g$ is a continuous function of locally bounded variation, on every compact interval $[0,T]$, we have a unique Radon (signed) measure $\mu_T$ such that
$$ \forall 0 \leq a <b \leq T, \quad \mu_T(a,b] = g(b) -g(a). $$
and the definition is consistent for any $T>0$, in the sense that, if $0<S<T$ and $A$ is a Borel subset of $[0,S]$ then
$$ \mu_S(A) = \mu_T(A). $$
However, we can not extend this measure to all of $\mathbb R_+ = [0,+\infty)$, because we would have a signed measure for which some sets would have measure $+\infty$ and other sets would have measure $-\infty$.
Regarding the your side question.
If $g$ is increasing and right-continuous, we can extend $(\mu_T)_{T>0}$ to a Radon $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on all of $\mathbb R_+$.  Just define
$$ \forall 0 \leq a <b < +\infty, \quad \mu(a,b] = g(b) -g(a). $$
It is easy to prove that $\mu$ is a Radon measure (not a signed measure). Moreover,
$$\mathbb R_+ = (0,1] \cup (1,2] \cup \cdots = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}(n, n+1]$$
and, for all $n \in \Bbb N$, we have $\mu( (n, n+1]) = g(n+1) - g(n) < \infty$. So $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.
